# MySQL Make Grant-Statement Case-Aware?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are currently facing a bug with MySQL 5.7 at a customer.

It is desired to grant some privileges to a user on certain tables only.

So, statements would look like this:

```
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `db`.`Table1` TO 'altium'@'%'
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `db`.`Table2` TO 'altium'@'%'
```

Now, when running `SHOW GRANTS for altium`, the result is:

```
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `db`.`table1` TO 'altium'@'%'
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `db`.`table2` TO 'altium'@'%'
```

Note the smaller `t` of the tablenames. This now has the weired result that:

- The user is able to run `SELECT * FROM Table1` with no problems.
- When running `SHOW TABLES;` it returns an empty set. (Also Applications like MySQL Workbench are unable to show the tables)

So it seems, that the `SHOW TABLES` Statement filters out tables based on a *Case-Sensitive* comparision - but we cannot provide the proper Grant-Statements, because mysql itself turns them into lower case table names.

Verified with a table, where the table is actually lowercase - there `Show Tables` works as expected.

Any workaround known? (Not yet possible to upgrade that mysql)

---

Update: I just tested this in my home lab, which runs a later version of MariaDB (10.6.5) - and the behaviour is EXACTLY the same. So I'm either missing the obvious here - or that's a bug living deep in the (legacy) code of mysql:

Steps to reproduce (Windows machine, using `lower_case_table_names=2`):

```
CREATE TABLE `atable` (
  `idatable` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idatable`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

CREATE TABLE `Btable` (
  `idBtable` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBtable`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

CREATE USER 'tester'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `db`.`atable` TO 'tester'@'%' with grant option;
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `db`.`Btable` TO 'tester'@'%' with grant option;

SHOW GRANTS FOR tester;
```

`SHOW GRANTS` already returns the lower-case of version as for mysql 5.4:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `db`.`btable` TO `tester`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION   |
|GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `db`.`atable` TO `tester`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

log on with tester.

```
C:\Users\me>mysql -utester -ppassword
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 6
Server version: 10.6.5-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> use db;
Database changed
MariaDB [db]> show tables;
+------------------------------+
| Tables_in_db                 |
+------------------------------+
| atable                       |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [db]> select * from atable;
Empty set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [db]> select * from btable;
Empty set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [db]> select * from Btable;
Empty set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [db]> select * from user;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'tester'@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

`SHOW TABLES` only shows the `atable`, where the table name is matching the `GRANT`-case. Querying both tables however works. But `GRANT` for BTable cannot be created with a upper-case B-letter.

Created a bug report for mariadb:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30765

Comment: See [MySQL Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). You apparently have [`lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) enabled.

Comment: @Barmar nope, isn't enabled. Tables are actually Upper-Case, hence the problem to provide the matching GRANT.

Comment: What operating system, Unix or Windows? Windows table names are case-insensitive.

Comment: It's Windows, and `lower_case_table_names` is set to `2`. So, yes, whole thingy runs case-insensitive, including queries - EXCEPT `Show Tables;` - it seems to compare case-sensitive and for whatever reason, every `GRANT` is turned into lower-case table names. so, having a `Grant ... table1` does exclude `Table1` from `Show Tables`.

Comment: Since everything is case-insensitive, why does it matter how it's stored in the `GRANT`?

Comment: Because `Show Tables` is apparently NOT case-insensitive. (At least for mysql 5.7 - I will check later with more recent versions)

Comment: That does sound like a bug. Have you searched the bug database for it? Maybe it's fixed in 8.x.

Comment: Did not yet find anything related. I will review it with a more recent version, and if the issue is still there, fill a bug report (but creating a bug report for 5.7 doesn't make sence, if it's fixed)

Comment: @Barmar just tested with MariaDB 10.6 - behaves exactly the same way. Added example to reproduce.